# Send ssh command from Java code

Tags: java, ssh

can anybody show moe how to send from java ssh command ( example ssh root@192.168.0.2 "ls" ) ?
What class do I need ?

Comment: possible dublicates http://stackoverflow.com/questions/570450/running-commands-over-ssh-with-java and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/995944/ssh-library-for-java

Comment: Remote access for root? Generally not recommended.

Comment: you can use JSch library, but dont do directory listing with command "ls", better use sftp from the same library JSch, much easier to browse remote filesystem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SSH library for Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995944/ssh-library-for-java)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [JSch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/index.html) or any other Java library. Google will help you.

Although, usually I find it more convenient to execute ssh commands from build script. E.g., there's an [Ant task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/sshexec.html) for that.

Comment: +1 for the sshexec ant-task reference as a more convenient way

Answer (score 14):

Using [sshj](https://github.com/shikhar/sshj/):

```
SSHClient ssh = new SSHClient();
ssh.loadKnownHosts();
ssh.connect("nameOfServer");
ssh.authPublickey("userId");
Session session = ssh.startSession();
Command cmd = session.exec("yourCommand");
System.out.println(cmd.getOutputAsString());
session.close();
ssh.disconnect();
```

Comment: Thanks for the option. Just bear in mind that this library has 5 library dependencies.

Answer (score 3):

an other lib we use is http://www.ganymed.ethz.ch/ssh2/