# How can I execute SSH command line using Java?

Tags: java, ssh, exec

I've tried

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ssh guest@guest password");
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("do something at guest@guest");
```

But this prompts me for password.
I would like to automate ssh login and do something like create a file in the remote client.

What's the best way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The best way to automate the login is by setting up `ssh` keys. See the [HOWTO](http://paulkeck.com/ssh/).

As to the actual `ssh` interaction, instead of executing the external command, it probably makes sense to use a suitable library. See [SSH library for Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995944/ssh-library-for-java) for some pointers.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider this library

http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/index.html

Or
sshj

https://github.com/shikhar/sshj/

Here you will find a similar question:
[Send ssh command from Java code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4723508/send-ssh-command-from-java-code)