# How to create a file / directory in remote machine using Java11

Tags: java, nio, java-11, openjdk-11

I would like to know how to create a file / directory in remote machine using Java11 ?

I did try to use:

```
process = Runtime.getRuntime()
         .exec("ssh root@" + hostname + " 'mkdir -p "+mdbDir+"'")
         .wait() or waitFor();
```

But i am getting an exception even though i use **wait()**

```
java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException: process has not exited
```

Please let me know what can be done.

Comment: You probably have to read command's output to see what happened.

Comment: @antoniossss you can help me reading if you know.

Comment: Note that there are Java SSH implementations out there as well. I never like executing an external application.

Comment: [`wait`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait--) and [`waitFor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor--) are entirely different methods with an entirely different purpose. You should never mix them up. And since you didn’t notice the `IllegalMonitorStateException` when calling `wait` without synchronization, you must have some sort of “catch all and ignore” construct in your code. Another thing you should never do.

Comment: @Holger Thank you i dint use both together wait and waitFor .

Comment: You shouldn’t use `wait` at all, neither together with `waitFor` nor alone. The method `wait` is just wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

You should only call `Process.waitFor()` without `Process.wait()`. `Object.wait` is about synchronization. It has nothing to do with process management.

Answer (score -1):

You have a good example here about how to use an `SSHClient` from sshj, more specific for the task that you want to do:

[Send ssh command from Java code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4723508/send-ssh-command-from-java-code)

Moreover, you will probably need a trusted connection with the target server. Check if an SSH connection from your system requires a password, if your system and the server has a trusted connection it will no ask for the password.

If you still want to use your approach without a library I guess that the problem is that the execution is waiting for some input like adding the host to the knowhosts or the password, and that is the reason for the process not exiting.