# How can I connect to a unix box remotly and startup/shutdown a server?

Tags: java, unix

I am sort of new to this but even if someone could tell me how to connect to a unix box remotely using Java I think I could get the rest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If an ssh connection would be fine for you, have a look at [JSch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/).

Answer (score 1):

Check this out:

http://javassh.org/space/start

It's under GPL license.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of Java SSH clients you could use:

- http://javassh.org/
- http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/
- http://www.ganymed.ethz.ch/ssh2/

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to open a session on ssh to a UNIX machine. In that case, you may want to have a look at [JSch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/)

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to use Java? Most likely you can just ssh using gitbash, putty, a terminal.  It depends on your environment.

However if you need to do this from within Java take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/570450/running-commands-over-ssh-with-java).